# How to fix 'send: spawn id exp4 not open while executing "exp_send -s "$cmd\r"" ' error

Tags: tcl, putty, spawn

My TCL file has code like below,

```
proc executeCmd {cmd {file ""}} {
    set out ""
    set output ""
    set send_slow {20 0.1}
    set adminFlag 0
    exp_send -s "$cmd\r"
    for {set i1 0} {$i1 < 12} {incr i} {
            set intimeout 0
            expect {
                    # other options to check 'hostname', 'more', 'press any to continue' regexes
                    # ...
                    -regexp {^(.*)Press any key to continue.*$} {
                        set output [cleanOutput $expect_out(buffer)]
                        if {[regexp -- {\w+} $file]} {
                            append out $output
                            flush $fo
                            flush $clf
                        } else {
                            append out $output
                        }
                        exp_sleep 0.1
                        exp_send -s " "
                        exp_continue
                    }

                    timeout {
                            #log_msg INFO "TIMED OUT...."
                            puts "TIMED OUT"
                            set intimeout 1
                            puts "Executing $cmd >>> waiting for response from $hostname"
                    }
            }
            if {$intimeout} {
                    exp_send -s " "
            } else {
                    break
            }
    }
    return $out
}

spawn $plinkLoc -telnet $routerIP -P $routerPort
set out [executeCmd "term width 0"]
```

After executing this TCL through command prompt I am facing error saying,

```
send: spawn id exp4 not open
    while executing
"exp_send -s "$cmd\r""
    (procedure "executeCmd" line 28)
    invoked from within
"executeCmd "term width 0""
    invoked from within
"set out [executeCmd "term width 0"]""
```

This line 28 in TCL code is 'set' statement which is prior to 'executeCmd' proc, have updated the file for query purpose.

Comment: Are you spawning a script ? What is `$plinkLoc` ?

Comment: $plinkLoc is path to plink.exe , m trying to connect to the router through spawning.

Comment: same script was working perfectly fine before, in while my window got updated, i am not sure if its the problem because of that or any TCL patches expiry. Couldn't track it even after so much of digging...

Answer (score 0):

You have to either pass `spawn_id` to the procedure or declare the spawn_id as `global`.

Add this line inside procedure

```
global spawn_id
```

Comment: Expect variable scoping is different from Tcl's: if a variable is not found in the local scope, expect will look in the global scope. Since the `spawn` command occurs in the main (global) namespace, the expect and send commands in the executeCmd proc will be able to find the spawn_id. Check the "Caveats" section of the [expect man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/expect.1.html).

Comment: @glennjackman : Thanks Sir, for correcting me. I hope whatever I have mentioned is applicable when  `spawn`  command itself is used inside a procedure.

Comment: Yes, when spawning in a proc, need to make spawn_id global.